# What is the difference between these two ways of defining controllers?

Tags: angularjs

Regarding controller definitions. What is the difference between this...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function CarouselCtrl($scope) {
   ...
}
```

and this...

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myAppModule.controller('CarouselCtrl', function($scope){
    ...
}
```

It seems that both of them get access to ui.bootstrap.
How is the first CarouselCtrl function connected to my angular.module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is a global function. You should not be using it. It is "connected" to your module because it is connected to everything.

The second one is a controller declared in a module. this is fine and it's a usual approach. You can have a module with directives, a module with services, etc. [More about organizing your application](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps)

The safest option is using annotations:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myAppModule.controller('CarouselCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    ...
}]);
```

As Golo Roden points out in the comments, you can avoid global variables by referencing the controller like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(...);
```

This way the application can be minified without breaking, as explained in the manual https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di
the reason is that dependency injection looks up components by name. you can minify the name of a function but values in arrays will never be altered. The order in the array is important. it matches 1-1 with the parameters in the function.

Comment: additionally if you'd like to use ngmin to ensure your minification does not break the application use this / second approach

Comment: Please note that you, too, are introducing a global variable: `myAppModule`. IMHO it's way better to dynamically resolve the module by calling `angular.module('myApp').controller(...);`. This way you can skip the variable `myAppModule`, so you do not have a global one, and it also works across files.

Comment: yeah that's true. thanks for pointing that out! I normally use closures to avoid the mess.

Comment: This might be a stupid question... But when i define my controller like this: `angular.module('myApp').controller(...);` How do i then define the second controller?

Comment: you can either write two lines : `angular.module('myApp').controller('shopsCtrl', f1); angular.module('myApp').controller('foodCtrl', f2);`, or you can do: `angular.module('myApp').controller('shopsCtrl', f1).controller('foodCtrl', f2);` it's simmilar to the pattern you find when you use promises: `.success(/* something */).error(/*something*/);` read the manual https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: oh, ok. I thought this: `angular.module('myApp').controller('shopsCtrl', f1).controller('foodCtrl', f2);` would create a childController. But inheritance seems to be about how you nest the controllers in the template...